# Image clustering - problem with matlab function

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cluster-analysis

Curently I'm writing a project about image recognition and clusterization. In publication which is a basis for my project there is this equation

[image]

Variables description is given below

> Rj - is a rotation matrix of j-th
>   cluster
>
> t_j - is a translation vector of j-th
>   cluster
>
> p*ij - is a i-th point from j-th
>   cluster
>
> x_i - is a i-th point from the image

I had a little problem with writing this function so I asked the author of publication if he could share with me a source code. Here is what I got

```
ddx=D.x-Q.translation(1);
 ddy=D.y-Q.translation(2);
 st=sin(Q.theta); ct=cos(Q.theta);  R=[ct -st; st ct]; % rotation matrix
 qq=R*[ppx0; ppy0];
 qqd2=sum(qq.*qq,1);
 Q.scale=sum((ddx.*qq(1,:)+ddy.*qq(2,:)).*Um) / sum(qqd2.*Um);
```

Here `D.x`, and `D.y` are the coordinates of data points

`Q.translation` (a vector), `Q.scale`, and `Q.theta` are the transform parameters

`ppx0` and `ppy0` are the *x-* and *y-* coordinates of *p**<sub>*ij*</sub>

`Um` is the matrix containing [*U<sup>m</sup><sub>ij</sub>*]

However I have a hard time with understanding this solution. First of all I don't understand why he uses array multiplication (operator `.*`) instead of matrix multiplication (operator `*`) what is more it seems that he takes only one/first point `p*`

I hope somebody will help me to try this source code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

it looks like `ppx0` and `ppy0` are not coordinates, but rather vectors or coordinates. This way,

```
R*[ppx0; ppy0] =
[ct -st ; st ct] * [x_0 x_1 ... x_N-1 ; y_0 y_1 ... y_N-1]
```

Therefore `qq` is a 2xN vector, just like `[ppx0; ppy0]`.

In `qqd2=sum(qq.*qq,1)`, the `.*` operator is used, because you're actually squaring every value of a matrix to find the square distance of each of its coordinate pairs later on.

In `ddx.*qq(1,:)+ddy.*qq(2,:)` the `.*` operator is used as a shortcut to replace a double sum. In other words, istead of taking a sum of each matrix product individually (which in itself is a sum of multiplication), they first performed all necessary multiplications and then took a sum. (I hope this makes sense). You can prove all of these work with some basic matrix algebra.